# Oracle SQL to bring back results not in

Tags: oracle

If I have a table something like this:

```
VALUE OWNER
--------------
test1 owner1
test2 owner1
test3 owner1
test4 owner1
test5 owner1
test1 owner2
test3 owner2
test5 owner2
```

How do I bring back just the following for owner1

```
test2
test4
```

Basically I want all results where owner1 but not owner2.

Thanks in advance

KS

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read up on `minus`, `(not) in` and `(not) exists`.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from tablename where OWNER = 'owner1' and `value` NOT IN (
select value from tablename where OWNER = 'owner2')
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
WITH my_data AS
  (SELECT 'test1' AS value, 'owner1' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test2' AS value, 'owner1' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test3' AS value, 'owner1' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test4' AS value, 'owner1' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test5' AS value, 'owner1' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test1' AS value, 'owner2' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test3' AS value, 'owner2' AS owner FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'test5' AS value, 'owner2' AS owner FROM dual)
SELECT
    value
  FROM my_data
WHERE owner = 'owner1'
MINUS
SELECT
    value
  FROM my_data
WHERE owner = 'owner2'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select value from t where owner = 'owner1'
Minus
Select value from t where owner = 'owner2'